# How to use a binary variable to indicate whether two continuous variables have the same value or not in an MILP problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to add a constraint to my MILP minimization problem. It should fulfill the following functionality: if non-negative continuous variables `a` and `b` have different value, then the value of `a` is added to the objective function; if `a` and `b` take the same value, then the objective function stays the same as before.

I am thinking about using a binary variable `z` as the indicator of whether `a == b`. I was thinking about using something like big-M expression but did not come up with one that suits my need. Is there any way to achieve that without including any 'if' statements in the constraint? I am using pyomo in my optimization problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,

Megan

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
   min f(x,a,b) + y
       -M⋅δ ≤ a-b ≤ M⋅δ
       y ≥ a - N⋅(1-δ) 
       δ ∈ {0,1}
       a,b,y ≥ 0
```

where M is a constant with M ≥ |a-b| and N is a constant with N≥a. δ is a binary variable.

If a=b, then either a=0 or δ=0, so y=0.
If a≠b, then δ=1, so y=a.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your objective expression, obj is `f(x)` with x is optimization vector. Now adding `a` will change objective variable to say `f(x)+f(a)` where `f(a) =a` as per your requirement.
`z` is binary
`ez <= a-b <= Mz`
`ez <= b-a <= Mz`
where `e` is a small number, may be like `min[(a-b),(b-a)]` & `e<0` and M`=a+b`
Using solution from [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond), lets define two more binary variables `y1` and `y2`
Additional constraints to force `y1=1` when `b-delta<a`, 0 otherwise and `y2=1` when `a<b+delta`, 0 otherwise, delta is a small positive number
`a-b+delta <= My1`
`b-a-delta <= M(1-y1)`
`b+delta-a <= My2` 
`a-b-delta <= M(1-y2)`
 `y1+y2 <= 2-z`: Both `y1,y2=1` when `b-delta<=a<=b+delta` implies `a=b`

Then obj `= f(x) + zf(a)` where `zf(a)` can be further linearized by following
Let variable `c` be a continuous variable of same domain as `a`.
Additional constraints
 `c <= zM`
 `-zM <= c`
 `f(a) - (1-z)M <= c`
 `c <= f(a) + (1-z)M`
Then obj `=f(x) + c`

Comment: Don't understand this.  `ze <= a-b`, `ze <= b-a` implies `z=0` and `a=b`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen is it correct now?

Comment: Looks very complex to me. I think we can do this differently.